# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal not working in eclipse. Modal Pop up coming at the bottom of the page not as popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap

[Output from Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC0oi.png)JS Fiddle example is working but when i try to implement the same on the Eclipse it is not working. No Error also. What would be the issue for this.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ribizli/CRNvB/

Comment: Yes. I think your javascript and bootstrap files are not loaded in DOM. Please check the URL's used for you JS and CSS files..

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript and bootstrap files are not loaded in DOM.
Please recheck the URL's used for you JS and CSS files..

Comment: Script file is loaded in the DOM. I have verified it. There is some issue with this cript only. <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>

Comment: Please use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js instead of your unavailable CDN

Comment: I have added the plunker. Please check it.  It seems to be the same. https://plnkr.co/edit/S6IKhXy00vb4tgtw9Z8s?p=preview